# Hibernate Entity with 3 collections misbehave only with 1 of them

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

**Problem**:
Hibernate can update Cluster, Vms, and LoadBalancers fine but any Dns deletion also causing to the 1st record to be deleted.
Example:
I have 4 Dnses, and I delete Dns #3, at the database I see #2 & #4 where #1 & #3 were deleted.
The same activity on Vm or LoadBalancer works fine.

**Additional information**:
I am using Spring boot 2.7.8 and the update is done via EntityManager:

```
public Cluster update(Cluster cluster) {
    return em.merge(cluster);
}
```

I have Custer within I have @OneToMany to Vm, Dns, and LoadBalancer (Dns and LoadBalancer are practically the same, I just separated them in-case in the future they won't be the same)
Vm, Dns, and LoadBalancer mapping Cluster by @ManyToOne

**Cluster**:

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cluster", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
public List\<Dns\> getDnses() {
    return dnses;
}
```

**Vm, Dns, and LoadBalancer**:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "cluster_id", nullable = false)
public Cluster getCluster() {
    return cluster;
}
```

**Create tables**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS boot_server.cluster(
    id            INT(6)        UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name          VARCHAR(30)   NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    comment       VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL,
    status        VARCHAR(25)   NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ACTIVE',
    creation_date TIMESTAMP     NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    updated_date  TIMESTAMP     NULL DEFAULT NULL
)  ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS boot_server.dns(
    id            INT(6)        UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    hostname      VARCHAR(50)   NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    ip            VARCHAR(50)   NOT NULL,
    cluster_id    INT(6)        UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    status        VARCHAR(25)   NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ACTIVE',
    creation_date TIMESTAMP     NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    updated_date  TIMESTAMP     NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_DNS_CLUSTER_ID FOREIGN KEY (cluster_id) REFERENCES boot_server.cluster(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
)  ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

1. I also tried unifying Dns and LoadBalancer to 1 table but the same behavior occurred.
2. When I tried the same after removing Dns from Cluster Vm and LoadBalancer worked fine too.

Comment: Have you implemented an equals or hashcode for the entities by any chance? That can create all sorts of weird behaviour if they are not implemented correctly and in a compatible way with Hibernate.

Comment: Yes in all entities auto generated by IntelliJ, Id excluded since it can be null and that not advised

Comment: That's probably the problem. I would suggest you to read this [blog](https://thorben-janssen.com/ultimate-guide-to-implementing-equals-and-hashcode-with-hibernate/) and the [Equals and Hashcode](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-model-pojo-equalshashcode) section of the Hibernate user guide. The 'best' approach to this is to not have an equals/hashcode defined on any entity (unless you really need one).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am not using Hibernate 6.
That's not explaining why LB which is the same object with different name works fine.
Before saving the Cluster, Vm, Lb and Dns collections seems to be in the correct numbers. After saving it seems to lose the 1st Dns

Comment: I completely removed the equals and the hashCode for the test and the same behavior occurred.

Comment: Sorry Sharon, that was my only idea. A couple of things I would do: Check that after removing the entry from the list, you do indeed have 3 items. And also to check the SQL that hibernate is generating as it might give a hint on what/where is the mapping error.

Comment: @Augusto thanks a lot for trying, the list seems OK, The returned entity from Hibernate seems OK but on the Database is otherwise. I also switch to Oracle XE edition but the same behavior.
For now, as a workaround I moved on the update part to the JDBC Template :(